# Как сделать отдачу exe файла?

Tags: php, google-chrome, exe

Есть код:

```
$file_d = '/download/tmp_file/'.$rand_name.'/qwerty.exe';
$file_n = 'qwerty.exe';
    if (ob_get_level()) {
      ob_end_clean();
    }
    // заставляем браузер показать окно сохранения файла
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file_n));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_d));
    // читаем файл и отправляем его пользователю
    readfile($file_d);
    exit;
```

Файл отдает но он не рабочий + еще и ошибку хром говорит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если отдаю просто:

```
header( 'Refresh: 0; url=/download/tmp_file/'.$rand_name.'/qwerty.exe' );
```

то все норм!
Как мне правильно отдать файл что бы не было предупреждений от хрома и что-бы подпись не слетала?

P.S.: Отдаю на отдельной странице! (Сейчас если делать через редирект хедер то при клике перенаправляет на страницу down.php, у меня при клике на СКАЧАТЬ открывается ещё окно с информацией, нужно что-бы работало без редиректа)

Comment: Скорее всего никак не выйдет: подпись файла если и есть, то в недоверенных, сайт тоже в недоверенных, вот хром и блочит. И правильно делает.

Comment: Попробуйте в архиве отдавать